# GetServerSideProps doesn't seem to be called

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Why can't I see the posts? All I see is the H1 element with All Posts. Otherwise nothing happens. In debug mode I don't see the URL being called either. I use Next.JS 13. If I try the whole thing in REACT, without getServerSideProps() of course, I have no problem - everything works.

Main.js:

```
import React from "react";

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
let allPosts = await res.json();

return {
props: {
  allPosts: allPosts.map((post) => post.title),
  },
 };
};

const Posts = ({ allPosts }) => {
return (
<div>
  <h1>All Posts</h1>
  {allPosts?.map((post, idx) => (
    <div key={idx}>{post}</div>
  ))}
  </div>
   );
 };

export default Posts;
```

layout.jsx:

```
 export default function RootLayout() {
 return (
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Digital</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <Main></Main>
  </body>
</html>
 );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me try this:

```
const Home = ({ allPosts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {allPosts.map((post, index) => (
        <p key={index}>
          <span>{index + 1}: </span>
          {post}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  let allPosts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      allPosts: allPosts.map((post) => post.title),
    },
  };
};
```

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ucxs.png)